# What does "That's O.P." mean?

Tags: slang, abbreviations

What does "That's O.P." mean?  It's an achievement in a game.  The abbreviation "O.P." obviously doesn't mean "Original Poster" in this context.  I think it may stand for surprise.

Can somebody give me an accurate explanation?

Comment: Can you please give the name of the game? "OP" means several different things in different contexts; in gaming it can mean "overpowered" i.e. too strong relative to other characters' abilities, but even there we'd need to see the context to say exactly what the intention is.

Comment: The name of the game is valdis story.The achivement is "Deal 1000+ damage in a single hit"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say: OP = over-powered

Comment: The most likely meaning is over-powered. I'm a very active gamer and certain initialisms like OP are present and mean the same thing in nearly every online game. By itself, it might be ambiguous,  but "That is OP" is very clear to someone familiar with the jargon. It's like FPS or DPS. They could mean something different, but they usually don't .  @CrazyEyes

Answer (score 1):

In Military Realism games, it might be used as 'Enemy is Operational Personnel'.

Essentially, that has the same effect as another usage of 'That's OP', which is likely to be referring to a weapon/skill being 'overpowered'.

You may hear players say O.P.O.P, which is Over Powered Operational Personnel.  When you hear that specific term run as fast as you can, because the person to whom they are referring is a serious bad ass.